# Can Rust Use Mocks Only For Some Tests?

Tags: rust

For example, in non-unit test code:

```
#[cfg(and(test, use_mock))]
use crate::MockObject as Object;
#[cfg(or(not(test), not(use_mock)))]
use crate::Object;
```

And in test:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
   use super::*;
   #[cfg(test)]
   fn test_without_mocks {
     // code will use crate::Object
   }

   #[cfg(test)]
   #[use_mock] // indicate this test needs to use mock
   fn test_with_mocks {
     // code will use crate::MockObject
   }
}
```

Feature may do that, but require to pass in `cargo test` command. Is there a way to do everthing in code?

Comment: Use a generic and call either `code_to_test::<Object>()` or `code_to_test::<MockObject>()`.

Comment: Why do you need two different functions? You can just use one and refer to `Object` that depending on the `cfg` may be `Object` or `MockObject`.